# Terraform use backend on module

Tags: amazon-s3, terraform, terraform-provider-aws, terraform-template-file

I need to create optimize the structure of terraform.

Have on root path variables which I imported like module 
/variables.tf

```
variable "aws_profile" { default = "default" }
variable "aws_region" { default = "us-east-1" }
```

After have a module folder 
/ec2_instance/main.tf

```
module "global_vars" {
  source = "../"
}

provider "aws" {
  region  = module.global_vars.aws_region
  profile = module.global_vars.aws_profile
}

terraform {
  backend "s3" {
    encrypt = true
    bucket  = "some_bucket"
    key     = "path_to_statefile/terraform.tfstate"
    region  = "region"
    profile = "profile"
  }
}

module "instances_cluster" {
  some actions
}
```

It's working, but I need to move backend and provider part to main.tf on root folder and after include like the module. 
How I can do this?

I have tried to create /main.tf on root folder with backend part, but they are not working and backed writing state files locally.

Answer (score 1):

You'd have to a bit of refactoring but these are the steps I would take

1. Run `terraform plan` in root and `ec2_instance` modules to verify zero changes so refactoring can begin
2. Comment out the `backend` for `ec2_instance/main.tf`
3. Place the backend from `ec2_instance/main.tf` into root `main.tf`
4. In the root `main.tf`, make a reference to `ec2_instance` module
5. Run `terraform plan` in root module and note the creations and deletions
6. For each creations and deletion pair, create a `terraform state mv` statement and run each
7. Verify the `terraform plan` has zero changes